# Redshift performance difference between CTAS and select count

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-redshift

I have query `A`, which mostly left joins several different tables.

When I do:

```
select count(1) from (
    A
);
```

the query returns the count in approximately 40 seconds. The count is not big, at around 2.8M rows.

However, when I do:

```
create table tbl as A;
```

where A is the same query, it takes approximately 2 hours to complete. Query `A` returns 14 columns (not many) and all the tables used on the query are:

- Vacuumed;
- Analyzed;
- Distributed across all nodes (DISTSTYLE ALL);
- Encoded/Compressed (except on their sortkeys).

Any ideas on what should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

When using `CREATE TABLE AS` (CTAS), a new table is created. This involves copying all 2.8 million rows of data. You didn't state the size of your table, but this could conceivable involve a lot of data movement.

CTAS does not copy the `DISTKEY` or `SORTKEY`. The [`CREATE TABLE AS` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html) says that the default `DISTKEY` is `EVEN`. Therefore, the CTAS operation would also have involved redistributing the data amongst nodes. Since the source table was `DISTKEY ALL`, at least the data was available on each node for distribution, so this shouldn't have been too bad.

If your original table DDL included **compression**, then these settings would probably have been copied across. If the DDL did *not* specify compression, then the copy to the new table might have triggered the automatic compression analysis, which involves loading 100,000 rows, choosing a compression type for each column, dropping that data and then starting the load again. This could consume some time.

Finally, it comes down to the **complexity** of `Query A`. It is possible that Redshift was able to optimize the query by reading very little data from disk because it realized that very few columns of data (or perhaps no columns) were required to read from disk to display the count. This really depends upon the contents of that Query.

It could simply be that you've got a **very complex query** that takes a long time to process (that wasn't processed as part of the Count). If the query involves many `JOIN` and `WHERE` statements, it could be optimized by wise use of `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY` values.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE writes all data that is returned by the query to disk, count query does not, that explains the difference. Writing all rows is more expensive operation compared to reading row count.